# How to run mongoexport to export mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I am using MongoDB on Openshift for my application. But i'm not able to locate database files. And if i use mongoexport command where those files will be saved (i'm aware about --out option). Where is mongoexport util exists? And i'm not able to successfully run mongoexport on openshift.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First go to your repo folder.

```
cd app-root/repo/
```

Then run below `mongoexport` command.

```
mongoexport --host hostname --port port --authenticationDatabase admin --username admin --password password --db test --collection collection --out collection.json
```

`--authenticationDatabase` is must option when you specify username and password that exists in different database.

[Refer this documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) for more options.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution!  And thanks for posting the [forum thread](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/mongodb-files-storage-location).  If you plan on keeping backups on the gear, it helps to keep them in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.  Likewise, you can use [Rockmongo](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-manage-mongodb-on-openshift-with-rockmongo) to export your data